# Configure webpack to output images/fonts in a separate subfolders

Tags: webpack

I managed configure webpack to output CSS and JS into respective sub-directories, i.e. `public/asests/css` and `public/assets/js`. However, I don't know how to do the same for images and fonts.

In other words, I want to output images in `public/assets/images` folder and fonts into `public/assets/fonts` folder.

Here's my webpack config file:

```
var path = require('path');
var ExtractCSS = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve('private/js'),
    resolve: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.es6', '.json'],
    entry: {
        homepage: './homepage'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('public/assets'),
        publicPath: '/public/assets/',
        filename: 'js/[name].js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractCSS('css/[name].css')
    ],
    devServer: {
        contentBase: 'public'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.(es6|js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: ExtractCSS.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader')
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: ExtractCSS.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!less-loader')
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=1024'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I could figure this out by referring to [url-loader](https://github.com/webpack/url-loader) & [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack/file-loader) documentation on GitHub.

All, I needed to do was to add a **name** query-string parameter in loader to specify full path. I also learned that you can specify how files should be named in output location.

```
{
    test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader:'url-loader?limit=1024&name=images/[name].[ext]'
},
{
    test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'url-loader?limit=1024&name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
}
```

Comment: Hey, this was really helpful. But for some reason, only the fonts worked for me. The images do not get exported into a new images folder. Am I missing a plugin or would the fact I am using SVG's be an issue?

Comment: I had the same issue. I fixed it by using the file loader instead of the url-loader for images
`loader:'file?limit=1024&name=images/[name].[ext]'`

Comment: Is this for webpack 1? I get this error:  `Can't resolve 'file-loader&name=images/[name].[ext]`

Comment: Awesome answer and so useful, but aware that the `name` query in `?limit=1024&name=` is the right path of fonts inside dist `CSS` file.

Comment: I've been using Webpack for a couple years now and never thought of this. Amazingly helpful, thanks!

Comment: Can you please review my post? there is a git repo in my last comment https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader/issues/299

Answer (score 17):

**Webpack 5** case-

Keeping it here just in case someone is looking for a Webpack 5 solution to the requirement of outputting image/font assets into separate directories into the output path.

Webpack 5 replaces `raw-loader`, `url-loader` and `file-loader` with Assets Module and it has 4 new modules to handle assets. Read in more details here - https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/

To our problem statement, the following configuration outputs all fonts/svgs into the directory `fonts`. But if certain files are less than 8KB, it throws them inline.

```
  {
    test: /\.(woff(2)?|eot|ttf|otf|svg|)$/,
    type: 'asset',   // <-- Assets module - asset
    parser: {
      dataUrlCondition: {
        maxSize: 8 * 1024 // 8kb
      }
    },
    generator: {  //If emitting file, the file path is
      filename: 'fonts/[hash][ext][query]'
    }
  }
```

Similarly we could do the same for images -

```
  {
    test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$/i,
    type: 'asset/resource',  //<-- Assets module - asset/resource
    generator: {
      filename: 'images/[hash][ext][query]'
    }
  }
```

Outputs all images to `images` directory irrespective of file size.

Comment: Is it possible to have certain images inlined too? Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: @NickW Yes, by using "asset" instead of "asset/resource", from the [Webpack5 documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/): 
"asset automatically chooses between exporting a data URI and emitting a separate file."

Answer (score 13):

```
{ 
    test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff2?)(\?v=[a-z0-9=\.]+)?$/i,
    include: folders.npm,
    loader: 'file?name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
},
{
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|ico)$/i,
    include: folders.src,
    loaders: [
        'file?name=images/[sha512:hash:base64:7].[ext]',
        'image-webpack?progressive=true&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=true'
    ]
}
```

This is what I use in production. I often come across situation where *.svg pictures are used and SVG fonts for IE fallback. Here I assume font are always inside node_modules. I have also seen devs doing  `test: /fonts\/[w+].(svg|eot ....)`.

Comment: I do not know if this is standard node practice but using /node_modules/ instead of folders.npm helped me. I liked your approach because my fonts were also coming from node_modules folder

Comment: folders.npm is variable I declared at the beginning.

const paths = {
    root: path.resolve('.'),
    npm: path.resolve('.', '/node_modules')
    ... etc.
};

Comment: Can you please review my post? there is a git repo in my last comment github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader/issues/299

Comment: Hey @RickSanchez. I would guess that it has something to do with sass/postcss loaders. I recall having issues with those two when it came to resolving. On some occasion I wanted to include font-awesome, but including css inside scss had strange behaviour. Paths inside CSS were intact and FA's css use relative path as far as I remember.

Suggestion. Try to minimize config. Remove "minimize" fields as they are `true` when webpack in production mode is used. Also leave out sourceMap for now. Remove outputPath & publicPath to get flat structure of public assets and then we can build on that.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to solve this with [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack/file-loader)
If you're using the Webpack 4, you would use `use` instead of `loader`.

```
{
    test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
    use: ['file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]']
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Configure file/url-loader output path & file name**

You can read in the [official file-loader documentation](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/#name): there's a `name` parameter in the configuration object, where a path can be specified.

This would do the job:

```
                         // ...
        {
            test    : /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$/,
            loader  : 'url-loader',
            options: {
                limit : 70000,
                name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]'
            }
        },
                         // ...
```

I suggest you to take a look at the [available placeholders](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/#placeholders), to know what can be used in a file name.

Loaders usually have a configuration object available, even if you can pass the options like other devs suggested ( `loader:'url-loader?limit=1024&name=images/[name].[ext]'`)
I'd prefer using a plain object configuration, to have something more readable, and easier to configure/debug as well

**Output path**

There's an `outputPath` (optional) configuration param, in case one wants to override the default output path, which in any case must be configured ([check the docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/)).
I'm pretty sure that webpack for it's loaders will use the default output dir. In my project I've got this:

```
                         // ...
output: {
    path: helpers.publicPath(),      // local output path: <project-root>/public
    publicPath,                      // same path on the server: /myapp/public
    filename: 'js/[name].bundle.js', // default output configuration for js
    chunkFilename: 'js/[name].chunk.js'
},
                         // ...
```

**Note**

I'm not sure that you need to exclude the `node_modules` folder: in case that libraries like font-awesome or material-icons are used, then you need node_modules to be included. Webpack will automatically leave out files that are not useful to make the project build & run.
I would only exclude folders containing old legacy scripts that are not using imports and stuff like that, and I don't want to be considered by webpack in any case.